# Variable being passed to Shiny input not triggering observeEvent

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

Trying to understand why this code is not working, keep in mind I am not even a JavaScript novice. The observeEvent does not even get triggered.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(jsonlite)

ui <-
  {
    fluidPage(title = 'Title',
           useShinyjs(),
           actionButton(inputId = 'Button' , label = NULL),
           textAreaInput(inputId = 'Input4', label = 'Test4'),
           textInput(inputId = 'Input3', label = 'Test3')
    )
  }

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyjs::runjs(
    '
    var metadata = "{\"id\":[115],\"email\":[\"test_email_address\"]}";
    
    Shiny.setInputValue("Input3", metadata);
    '
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Input3, ignoreInit = T, {
    updateActionButton(inputId = 'Button', label = 'Success')
    updateTextAreaInput(inputId = 'Input4', value = input$Input3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,
         
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code works fine when I run it. When I type some text in the `textInput` the `observeEvent` gets triggered which updates the `actionButton` and the `textAreaInput`.

Comment: @stefan, I am trying to get the javascript to modify the input with Shiny.setInputValue("Input3", metadata), so the textAreaInput would display "{"id":[115],"email":["test_email_address"]}"

Comment: Thx for clarifying. Your JS code raises an error which you can see via the developer tools of your browser. The issue are the escaped double quotes. Try with `const metadata = "{\'id\':[115], \'email\':[\'test_email_address\']}"`, i.e. use escaped single quotes.

Comment: @stefan.  Thank you, yes correct escaping of quotes fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct escaping required

```
...
  shinyjs::runjs(
    "
    var metadata = '{\"id\":[115],\"email\":[\"test_email_address\"]}';
    
    Shiny.setInputValue('Input3', metadata, {priority: 'event'});
    "
  )
...
```